# How can I show a masked password of the correct length without making my website less secure?

Tags: html, passwords, data-masking

My web application contains a profile edit page where users can change their email address, password, etc. The password field is the HTML "password" type, so it automatically masks its contents with bullet characters. Passwords are saved in the database as hashes, so I don't load the actual password into the field, I just load the string "********," which displays as eight bullets. Then when the form is submitted, I check the submitted value, saving the new password if it's anything other than "********."

The problem is that users frequently send help tickets saying their password isn't saving correctly, because they entered a 6 or 10 or whatever length password but 8 dots are appearing when they return to the profile edit page. So the website is behaving as intended, but I'm getting tired of explaining this to users and am trying to think of how to show the accurate number of dots in the field.

The only thing I can think of is to save the password length alongside the hashed password whenever I save a password, then use that length to show the right number of dots. But this would be less secure because it would show a hacker how long each password is.

Another option is just to load the password field empty and hopefully users will be less confused by that. Or I could present this option as a "change password" form to indicate that the form is not trying to load the saved password.

But first I'd like to know if there is a trick to showing those dots accurately?

Comment: Unless you also store their password length, you can't give the "right" number of dots. What is dissuading you from the obvious solution of having the box be *empty*?

Comment: Why can't you just display placeholder text to indicate the purpose of the password field? `<input type="password" placeholder="New password" />` is pretty common. It'll disappear the moment a user starts to type in their password and is distinguished from the actual element's value by usually being a lighter color.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think that's obvious, when all the other fields show the existing values. I guess the crux of the problem is that the password field does work differently from the other fields, but it's a subtle difference and I want it to seem the same as the others to users.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the users would find that behaviour more or less confusing that the current one (that they're definitely confused by)? Have you tried some user research to determine that? What user research or hypothesis led you to the current behaviour? This seems more like a UI/UX problem than a programming one.

Comment: Yes, it becomes a UI problem if there is no acceptable programming solution to make all the fields appear to function the same way.

Comment: You're looking at this backwards. The feedback you're getting is on the user experience, *not* the technology. Currently you're trying to find the technological solution to what might be the wrong problem. *"I want it to seem the same as the others to users"* - do *they* want that? As it's categorically different, is it even appropriate to be in the same form?

Comment: Since the details of how a password is stored and retrieved are not something a user should have to think about, I think it is appropriate to make the process of changing the password the same as the process of changing the email address. In that case, a technological solution to support that would be ideal. I wanted to ask to see if there was a solution I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safe solution is, to handle a password-change on a dedicated page, independent of other user profile settings.

On the password-change form request the old password, the new password and possibly a confirmation of the new password. Don't pre populate this fields, they should not and cannot be shown correctly without compromising security.

The user profile page on the other hand should not contain any password information at all.